# Is it possible to do echo something if an ACF field DOESNT exist?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a radio button ACF fields in WordPress, with two buttons 'svarvning' and the other 'frasning', but my acf field also has a "custom" button as well

[image]

I want to echo the value of 'custom field' if *neither* of the 'svarvning' or 'frasning' are *true*.

Is this possible?
***I've got it to work if its TRUE***

```
<?php 
    if (get_field('kurstyp') !== 'svarvning' . 'frasning') { 
       echo "It's not equal!" 
    } else {
       die;
    }
?>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fix the condition check, as it stands, it is concatenating your options into one that doesn't exist.

```
<?php 
    if (get_field('kurstyp') !== 'svarvning' && get_field('kurstyp') !== 'frasning') { 
       echo "It's not equal!" 
    } else {
       die;
    }
?>
```

If you have a large amount of values to compare, you can also check if value is in a list of possibilities, something like this:

```
    $array=array('frasning', 'svarvning', 'etc');

    if (in_array(get_field('kurstyp'),$array))
    {
      echo 'Value found';
    } else {
      echo 'Not found';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this condition.

```
if( get_field('kurstyp') == 'svarvning' || get_field('kurstyp') == 'frasning' ){
    // Choice Value
} else {
    // Button value
}
```